# Regex doesn't find matches over whole string

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this code

```
String str = "bla#ff0000bla#000000bla"; // String I want to convert
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("/#([0-9a-fa-f]{6})/i"); // Regex that matches all hex color codes
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str); // Find pattern in string
Log.d("Matcher", String.valueOf(mat.matches())); // This returns false
```

Why does it return false? I'd like to do a while loop after with mat.find() (even that doesn't work). I want to get all hex color codes and get their position. (Hex codes look like #ff0000, #000000, #FF0000 etc)

This question seems short but that's all I got. No errors, no warnings, nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're using Javascript notation for Java.

  Ditch the initial `/` and replace the final `/i` with an initial `(?i)`, or use the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag instead.
- You also have a redundant definition of hex letters in your custom character class.
- Finally, use `Matcher#find` to iterate multiple matches, instead of matching the whole input with `Matcher#matches`.

**Example**

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("#([0-9a-f]{6})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);
while (mat.find()) {
    /* TODO something with mat.group()
     * with the given input String, you'd get:
     * #ff0000
     * #000000
     */
}
```

Finally, "must-read" literature [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).